# Gsv::buffer error

Tags: c++, gtkmm, coredump, gtksourceview

In my c++ project, I want to use a Gsv::buffer from GTKsourceview library.
I declare my buffer like this:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gsv::Buffer> buffer;
```

I create it :

```
buffer->create();
```

But when I want to use some inherited fonction from Gtk::buffer:

```
 buffer->set_text("somethings");
```

The executable exit and return:

> Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)

What is the problem?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a pointer, but you don't actually make it point anywhere. In essence, `buffer` is a null pointer.

From [the `RefPtr` default constructor refernece](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1RefPtr.html#a8b6c39656dbc5d452933b35faf352f74):

> Afterwards it will be null and use of `->` will cause a segmentation fault.

You need to explicitly create the object pointed to, using the ***`static`*** [`Gsv::Buffer::create`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceviewmm/stable/classGsv_1_1Buffer.html#a12f8871468e215e5b53761fa1e1654ae) function, like e.g.

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gsv::Buffer> buffer = Gsv::Buffer::create();
```

Comment: I wonder if the compiler should/does warn about the use of a static function via an object.

Comment: G++ my compiler don't warn about that. Thank you resolved my problem Thanks